# Differentiation, Duhamel

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, partial-differential-equations

Lets assume we define some function

$u(x,t):= \int\limits_0^t u(x,t;s) ds$

Then there is a part in my lecture where it says

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t)= u(x,t;t)+ \int\limits_0^t \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t;s) ds$

I don't understand where this comes from.

The topic here is to solve the inhomogenous wave equation using Duhamel principle, but I think that the part I don't understand here has nothing to do with the equation but is just a simple integration rule I don't see.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \; f(x,t,s) \,\mathrm{d}s = f(x,t,b(t)) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}b(t) - f(x,t,a(t))\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}a(t) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \; \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t,s) \,\mathrm{d}s $$

Since your $a(t) = 0$, the second term on the right vanishes.  Application of this expression has conditions: $f(x,t,s)$ and $\frac{\partial{f(x,t,s)}}{\partial t}$ is continuous in both $t$ and $s$ in an open neighborhood of $(x,t,s) \in \{x\} \times \{t\} \times [a(t),b(t)]$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Leibniz integral rule. Check it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)